# How can I moderate Facebook comments posted in my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

In meta I added

```html
<meta property="fb:admins" content="myID"/>
<meta property="fb:moderator" content="myID" />
```

I tried with both and individual

**code block**

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d){
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));</script>
<fb:comments href="<?php echo $currPage;?>" num_posts="20" width="500"></fb:comments>
```

Here 
**$currPage** is a dynamic page url

How can I moderate Facebook comments posted in my website?

Comment: What you mean please explain more @Ras4U

Comment: when some add a comment to my articles in my website I need to moderate it

Comment: i am having a same issue,but dint understand the answer below..how can you add app-id in head tag!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used the following method:

Put this in you Document in the head section:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="jayeshjain24ec" /> //username of moderater
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.something.com/" />
```

---

step 1) Go to this url : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

---

step 2) Enter your URL and click on debug.
In case if there is anything to be corrected,it will be mentioned here.

---

step 3)Correct all the warnings.Check the Scraped URL link at the bottom.Make sure it gets all the required Meta tags.

You will get a moderation option on your website once everything is ok.

### ALTERNATE SOLUTION:

Give yourself admin rights for the app(there is an option in settings).

go to this url: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?view=queue

Comment: in my app comments queue there is nothing, its empty. Though on my website I can see ppl are commenting using fb comment box

Comment: Click on Scrape Again - This is important part that needs to be mentioned in bold.

Answer (score 3):

just add facebook app_id in head tag

delete all the admins and then go to

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

and then setting  to set all the things