# How to add facebook comments to my website page using facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

With the new "[comments edge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/comments#publish)" implementation, does somebody know if I can let people to add comments to my website page using my own "add comment" form?

According to documentation you can publish a comment to any object_id (and an object_id could be a website url I think).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use the Comments Plugin (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments), or do you need to create something custom by all means?

Answer (score 0):

After a research, is not possible to use an external form to add facebook comments to a page, so we are using a "mix" with the facebook comments plugin to submit a comment, and our display comments view to show them. You can check it here: http://www.gemsmoda.com/p44026-ref-55.html (down bellow)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id))
            return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId='your-app-key'";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050121/how-can-i-moderate-facebook-comments-posted-in-my-website" data-numposts="5"></div>
```